# State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying out the new [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and have a Clock component with a `time` value which is supposed to increase every second. However, the value does not increase beyond one.

```js
function Clock() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Seconds: {time}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: There are great explanations to why this is happening. In case someone wants to also get the value https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679222/4427870 is a highly underrated hack around it.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

The reason is because the callback passed into `setInterval`'s closure only accesses the `time` variable in the first render, it doesn't have access to the new `time` value in the subsequent render because the `useEffect()` is not invoked the second time.

`time` always has the value of 0 within the `setInterval` callback.

Like the `setState` you are familiar with, state hooks have two forms: one where it takes in the updated state, and the callback form which the current state is passed in. You should use the second form and read the latest state value within the `setState` callback to ensure that you have the latest state value before incrementing it.

> **Bonus: Alternative Approaches**
>
> Dan Abramov goes in-depth into the topic about using `setInterval` with hooks in his [blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) and provides alternative ways around this issue. Highly recommend reading it!

```js
function Clock() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      setTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1); // <-- Change this line!
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Seconds: {time}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: @YangshunTay If I just wanna read state value within setInterval, how should I do?

Comment: @neosarchizo Have you read Dan's post? https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/. If you just want to read it, you can read the updated value as part of the rendering at the bottom. If you want to trigger side effects, you can add a `useEffect()` hook and add that state to the dependency array.

Comment: How would it look like if you would like to output the current state periodically with console.log in the setInterval function?

Comment: I want to read the time (in setInterval) and update if greater than some time. How to accomplish this?

Comment: @neosarchizo " If you just want to read it, you can read the updated value as part of the rendering at the bottom." Didn't get it can you kindly elaborate it a bit

Comment: That blog post is great. I would love to see it translated to a more generic example, though. Explaining how to do it for any callback would be nice to double-check my work against.

Comment: With empty brackets, UseEffect is supposed to run only once on mount, because it has no dependency on any resource, so how is it that it re-runs every second?

Comment: @Ferdossi where was it mentioned that the useEffect callback re-runs every second?

Answer (score 60):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that `useState` is only called once (as `deps = []`) to set up the interval:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
        setTime(time + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => window.clearInterval(timer);
}, []);
```

Then, every time `setInterval` ticks, it will actually call `setTime(time + 1)`, but `time` will always hold the value it had initially when the `setInterval` callback (closure) was defined.

You can use the alternative form of `useState`'s setter and provide a callback rather than the actual value you want to set (just like with `setState`):

```
setTime(prevTime => prevTime + 1);
```

But I would encourage you to create your own `useInterval` hook so that you can DRY and simplify your code by using `setInterval` [declaratively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming), as Dan Abramov suggests here in [Making setInterval Declarative with React Hooks](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/):

```js
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const intervalRef = React.useRef();
  const callbackRef = React.useRef(callback);

  // Remember the latest callback:
  //
  // Without this, if you change the callback, when setInterval ticks again, it
  // will still call your old callback.
  //
  // If you add `callback` to useEffect's deps, it will work fine but the
  // interval will be reset.

  React.useEffect(() => {
    callbackRef.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval:

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof delay === 'number') {
      intervalRef.current = window.setInterval(() => callbackRef.current(), delay);

      // Clear interval if the components is unmounted or the delay changes:
      return () => window.clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [delay]);
  
  // Returns a ref to the interval ID in case you want to clear it manually:
  return intervalRef;
}


const Clock = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [isPaused, setPaused] = React.useState(false);
        
  const intervalRef = useInterval(() => {
    if (time < 10) {
      setTime(time + 1);
    } else {
      window.clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, isPaused ? null : 1000);

  return (<React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={ () => setPaused(prevIsPaused => !prevIsPaused) } disabled={ time === 10 }>
        { isPaused ? 'RESUME ⏳' : 'PAUSE ' }
    </button>

    <p>{ time.toString().padStart(2, '0') }/10 sec.</p>
    <p>setInterval { time === 10 ? 'stopped.' : 'running...' }</p>
  </React.Fragment>);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```css
body,
button {
  font-family: monospace;
}

body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

p + p {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

button {
  margin: 32px 0;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Apart from producing simpler and cleaner code, this allows you to pause (and clear) the interval automatically by simply passing `delay = null` and also returns the interval ID, in case you want to cancel it yourself manually (that's not covered in Dan's posts).

Actually, this could also be improved so that it doesn't restart the `delay` when unpaused, but I guess for most uses cases this is good enough.

If you are looking for a similar answer for `setTimeout` rather than `setInterval`, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59274757/3723993.

You can also find declarative version of `setTimeout` and `setInterval`, `useTimeout` and `useInterval`, a few additional hooks written in TypeScript in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@swyg/corre.

Answer (score 45):

`useEffect` function is evaluated only once on component mount when empty input list is provided.

An alternative to `setInterval` is to set new interval with `setTimeout` each time the state is updated:

```
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setTime(time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, [time]);
```

The performance impact of `setTimeout` is insignificant and can be generally ignored. Unless the component is time-sensitive to the point where newly set timeouts cause undesirable effects, both `setInterval` and `setTimeout` approaches are acceptable.

Answer (score 23):

useRef can solve this problem, here is a similar component which increase the counter in every 1000ms

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const initalState = 0;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(initalState);
  const counterRef = useRef(initalState);

  useEffect(() => {
    counterRef.current = count;
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setCount(counterRef.current + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>The current count is:</h1>
      <h2>{count}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and i think [this article](https://itnext.io/how-to-work-with-intervals-in-react-hooks-f29892d650f2) will help you about using interval for react hooks

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution would be to use `useReducer`, as it will always be passed the current state.

```js
function Clock() {
  const [time, dispatch] = React.useReducer((state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'add') return state + 1
    return state
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      dispatch({ type: 'add' });
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Seconds: {time}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Why `useEffect` here is being called multiple times to update the time, while the dependencies array is empty, which means that the `useEffect` should be called only the first time the component/app renders?

Comment: @BlackMath The function inside `useEffect` is called only once, when the component first renders indeed. But inside of it, there is a `setInterval` which is in charge of changing the time on a regular basis. I suggest you read a bit about `setInterval`, things should be clearer after that ! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 5):

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds((seconds) => {
        if (seconds === 5) {
          setSeconds(0);
          return clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return (seconds += 1);
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
```

**Note**: This will help to update and reset the counter with useState hook. seconds will stop after 5 seconds. Because first change setSecond value then stop timer with updated seconds within setInterval. as useEffect run once.

Comment: It helped a lot. Question asked in all Interviews.

Answer (score 1):

This solutions dont work for me because i need to get the variable and do some stuff not just update it.

I get a workaround to get the updated value of the hook with a promise

Eg:

```
async function getCurrentHookValue(setHookFunction) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setHookFunction(prev => {
      resolve(prev)
      return prev;
    })
  })
}
```

With this i can get the value inside the setInterval function like this

```
let dateFrom = await getCurrentHackValue(setSelectedDateFrom);
```

Comment: That's a bad practice, React state setter should be pure, no side-effects. Also, calling some setter just to get the current value would still trigger a re-render of the current component.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Clock() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time => time + 1);// **set callback function here** 
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Seconds: {time}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Somehow similar issue, but when working with a state value which is an **Object** and **is not updating**.

I had some issue with that so I hope this may help someone.
We need to pass the older object merged with the new one

```
const [data, setData] = useState({key1: "val", key2: "val"});
useEffect(() => {
  setData(...data, {key2: "new val", newKey: "another new"}); // --> Pass old object
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as below it works fine.

```
const [count , setCount] = useState(0);

async function increment(count,value) {
    await setCount(count => count + 1);
  }

//call increment function
increment(count);
```

Comment: Where is setInterval used in your answer ?

Comment: Params of `increment` are also useless here.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the code from this blog. All credits to the owner. [https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/](https://overreacted.io/)

The only thing is that I adapted this React code to React Native code so if you are a react native coder just copy this and adapt it to what you want. Is very easy to adapt it!

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {Text} from 'react-native';

function Counter() {

    function useInterval(callback, delay) {
        const savedCallback = useRef();
      
        // Remember the latest function.
        useEffect(() => {
          savedCallback.current = callback;
        }, [callback]);
      
        // Set up the interval.
        useEffect(() => {
          function tick() {
            savedCallback.current();
          }
          if (delay !== null) {
            let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
            return () => clearInterval(id);
          }
        }, [delay]);
      }

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useInterval(() => {
    // Your custom logic here
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return <Text>{count}</Text>;
}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [loop, setLoop] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => setLoop(Math.random()), 5000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // DO SOMETHING...
  }, [loop])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your answer may solve the problem, it lacks an explanation about the code you have posted. Please check out the blogs on [answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a minimalist solution for:

1. Stop interval after N seconds, and
2. Be able to *reset it multiple times again* on button click.

(*I am not a React expert by any means my coworker asked to help out, I wrote this up and thought someone else might find it useful.*)

```
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true)
  const [inter, setInter] = useState(null)
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)

  const startCounting = () => {
    setSeconds(0)
    setDisabled(true)
    setInter(window.setInterval(() => {
        setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1)
    }, 1000))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      startCounting()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (seconds >= 3) {
        setDisabled(false)
        clearInterval(inter)
    }
  }, [seconds])

  return (<button style = {{fontSize:'64px'}}
      onClick={startCounting}
      disabled = {disabled}>{seconds}</button>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
 const myFunction = () => {
    // your code and your setState()
   // ....
  setToggle((prev) => !prev);
 };

useEffect(() => {
 const interval = setInterval(myFunction, 60 * 1000); // every one minute
return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [toggle]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Tell React re-render when time changed.[opt out](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

```js
function Clock() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => {
      setTime(time + 1);
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, [time]);

  return (
    <div>Seconds: {time}</div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Clock />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the timer will be cleared and reset after every `count` change.

Comment: And because so `setTimeout()` is preferred as pointed out by Estus