# JS return syntax looks weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import "./styles.css"

function usePersistentValue(initialValue) {
  return React.useState({
    current: initialValue
  })[0]
}

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const id = usePersistentValue(null)

  const clearInterval = () => window.clearInterval(id.current)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    id.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      setCount(c => c + 1)
    }, 1000)

    return clearInterval
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={clearInterval}>Stop</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root")
ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, rootElement)
```

here

```
function usePersistentValue(initialValue) {
      return React.useState({
        current: initialValue
      })[0]
    }
```

it seems a function call but followed by [0] makes no sense for me, especially what [0] doing here? is it valid javascript or a special syntax for react? my best guess here the [0] value gets assigned to `current` property ,am i right? but im still confused how array value get assigned to the `current` property, please help me explaining the syntax thank you

Comment: Perfectly valid, regular JS syntax. Your function returns the `0` property of whatever `React.useState()` returns.

Comment: `useState` data shouldn't be mutated. It looks like you'd need `useRef` instead. See [how to use it to manage a timer id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53090432/1218980).

Answer (score 2):

`[0]` just gets the `0` property from something, typically an array.

```js
function return_an_array() {
    return ["foo", "bar"];
}

const result = return_an_array()[0];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the same as:

```
const [id] = useState({ current: null });
```

`useState` returns an array of two values, the constant state value that you use *and do not change* and a "set" function that you use *to change the state*. You can see a "normal" example of that in the line `const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)`

The *weird* thing in this code is that they are working around the rules by changing the contents of `id` later without actually calling a function to set the updated state. Instead, they sweep it under the rug by hiding in a function.

Answer (score 0):

think of it like this

```js
return ( React.useState({ current: initialValue })[0] )
```

(parenthesis for emphasis)

So it first evaluates `React.useState({ current: initialValue })[0]` - which will result in something - *that* is what is being returned. the `[0]` is on the return value of `.useState` not the `return` statement.