# Problem with React useEffect in own npm package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, npm-package

We have made our own npm-package and I'm now working on a time out alert.
To get the time out to work right I need to have it inside a useEffect but I get error: *react.development.js:1465 Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call.* .

The file in the component in the npm package is in typescript but I don´t think that´s the problem.
.tsx:

```js
import * as React from "react";

/**
 * @param {string} close_button_title default "Stäng"
 * @param {"top" | "bottom"} alert_position fixes the alert to bottom och top
 * @param {"warning" | "success" | "danger" | "error"} alert_type success as default
 * @param {any} alert_text plain text or html elements whit text, if empty/null/false the Alert is not shown
 * @param {any} set_alert_text the set state (hook) for alert_test (ex: setAlertText), must be right to close alert both whit timeout and the close btn
 * @param {boolean} alert_inline used to get alert message inline in modal
 */

const TimeOutAlert = (props: {
    close_button_title: string;
    alert_position?: "top" | "bottom";
    alert_type?: "warning" | "success" | "danger" | "error";
    message_wrapper_id?: string;
    alert_text: any;
    set_alert_text: any;
    alert_inline?: boolean;
}) => {
    const {
        close_button_title = "Stäng",
        alert_position = "top",
        alert_type = "success",
        message_wrapper_id = null,
        alert_text,
        set_alert_text,
        alert_inline = false,
    } = props;

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (alert_text) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                set_alert_text("");
            }, 15 * 1000);
        }
    }, [alert_text]);

    let alertClasses = `message__alert__fixed--${alert_position}`;
    if (alert_inline) {
        alertClasses = "message__alert--inline";
    }

    if (alert_text) {
        return (
            <div
                className={`message__alert--${alert_type} ${alertClasses}`}
                id={message_wrapper_id}
            >
                {close_button_title && (
                    <button
                        className="icon icon--140 button--icon message__alert__button__close"
                        title={close_button_title}
                        onClick={() => set_alert_text("")}
                    >
                        close
                    </button>
                )}
                {alert_text}
            </div>
        );
    }
    return null;
};

export default TimeOutAlert;
```

index.ds

```js
import TimeOutAlert from "./TimeOutAlert";
import OneMorefrom "./OneMore";
import Some "./Some";
import Else from "./Else";

export {
    TimeOutAlert,
    OneMore,
    Some,
    Else,
};
```

If I remove the useEffect, it works but then the time out don´t work as it should.
When I use the package I import the component I want´t to use in my jsx-file or tsx-file.
I have made ten or something components but have not used hooks in any of them except for this one.

Where I use the components App.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TimeOutAlert } from "our-npm-package";

export default () => {
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("Alert meddelande");

    return (
        <>
        <TimeOutAlert alert_text={message} set_alert_text={setMessage}  />
```

I´m using react hooks in the main projects where I import this npm package so I usually know what´s the problem is but I don´t know way it´s not working now. I don´t usually use typescript, it´s just in the npm package to get intellisense when using it but I still think that it´s react thats the problem. But I could be wrong.

EDIT:

It's the useEffect that causes the error, useState throws the same error (tried to use that for changing the alertclass).

I have used this kind of timeouts in multiple projects that's why I want it in our react-components npm-package.

The full error message in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See ... for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
>
> at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1465)
> at Object.useEffect (react.development.js:1508)
> at TimeOutAlert (TimeOutAlert.js:14)
> at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14803)
> at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17482)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:18596)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23203)

Comment: I think you should also provide code for the component rendering `TimeOutAlert `

Comment: But what I you remove setTimeout, is still the same error?

Comment: And I see you don't clear your timeout so maybe try this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53090432/react-hooks-right-way-to-clear-timeouts-and-intervals

Comment: The problem is not whit the timeout, it works, it´s whit the layout-effect. I have written the same code directly in projects (not typescript). Get the same error whit useState so it´s not the timeout function that´s the problem is that react don´t except me usining useEffect