# React - adding search to a table, correct way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I added a search function for my table in React to filter out items fetched from an external webservice. Since I don't want to call the API every time you search for project I figured I'd assign the data retrieved to two different useState hooks.

One to hold the complete dataset and the other to contain the filtered items based on the search.

Could I write cleaner code without using 2 hooks? Any side effects of the way the code is handling this?

Any input is appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import DeleteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Delete';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';

export default function ShowProject() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'http://127.0.0.1:5000/pr'
            );
            setData(result.data);
            setFilter(result.data);
        }
        fetchData()
        
    }, []);

    const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
        const filteredRows = data.filter((row) => {
            return row.customer.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toString().toLowerCase());
        });
        if (searchedVal.length < 1) {
            setFilter(data)
        }
        else {
            setFilter(filteredRows)
        }
      };
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <TextField onChange={(e) => requestSearch(e.target.value)} />
                <Table>
                    <TableHead>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Project</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Code</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
                            <TableCell></TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableHead>
                    <TableBody>
                        {filter.map(item => (
                            <TableRow key={item.db_id}>
                                <TableCell>{item.project_name}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.project_code}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>{item.customer}</TableCell>
                                <TableCell><DeleteIcon /></TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        ))}
                    </TableBody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Two considerations, before even looking at your code-- 1) How frequently is the data updated?  Should the user expect to see updates to the data in the server reflected in their browser?  Because you have cached the data fetch, so they won't get fresh data unless the refresh the page or remount the component... 2) How large can the dataset be?  If it can be very large, you'd probably be better served by implementing pagination or lazy-loading and letting the server handle sorting/searching/etc rather than doing it in memory on the client machine.

Comment: 1) The dataset is updated approximately once a month, I do expect them to see a live update once I add a submit form allowing them to add new items to the db.
2) The dataset will grow over the years but within the first year i'm expecting around 200 objects so I would not consider it as a big dataset, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any particular reason to use the `filter` state variable. You're scanning `data` and assigning the filtered result to `filter` every time your `TextField` changes, so why not just do the filtering directly in the JSX and instead store the *query* text as state? More concretely, something like the following:

```
  const [searchedVal, setSearchedVal] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {/* simply set the query text here instead of triggering requestSearch */}
        <TextField onChange={(e) => setSearchedVal(e.target.value)} />
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Project</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Code</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Customer</TableCell>
              <TableCell></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data
              .filter((row) =>
                // note that I've incorporated the searchedVal length check here
                !searchedVal.length || row.customer
                  .toString()
                  .toLowerCase()
                  .includes(searchedVal.toString().toLowerCase()) 
              )
              .map((item) => (
                <TableRow key={item.db_id}>
                  <TableCell>{item.project_name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{item.project_code}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{item.customer}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    <DeleteIcon />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll adjust the code. Would this approach also improve the performance (imagine the dataset being quite large)?

Comment: Not particularly. This is just a cleaner way to do roughly the same thing you did. As another user noted, holding large datasets on the client is generally going to cause problems. You're better off doing pagination/lazy loading on the client side and handling filtering on the server side. In order to accomplish this, the server would need to expose an API that accepts a query string and results range (e.g. results 1-100, 101-200, etc.) and returns the relevant rows. On the client, you would either want a submit action or a slight delay between user input and API calls for performance's sake.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I'll keep that in mind for further development. So basically whenever the text input is changed it would trigger an API call with the current query string?

Comment: That's the idea, yes, with the caveat that you probably don't want to trigger the API call, which may be expensive, *immediately* on every keystroke. Instead, as I mentioned above, either give the user a submit button, or insert a slight delay after keystrokes before calling the API. `useEffect` and `setTimeout` are good candidates for the delay tactic (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090848/12162258) for the general idea). The idea is the effect triggers on every keystroke and sets a timeout to call the API, but the timeout gets cleaned up if the effect is triggered again

Comment: Got it. Added a expand/collapse button that fetches the payload that works fine for now. No I'm working on an auto-refresh of the table component when a post request is made from another function component. Thanks for the input so far.