# In React, what is the difference these useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () =>
      setTimeout(() => set_current_focus(index_map[comp_index]), 1000);
  }, [comp_index]);
```

and

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return setTimeout(() => set_current_focus(index_map[comp_index]), 1000);
  }, [comp_index]);
```

Based on my testing, there is no difference.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: What should the `useEffect` do? `set_current_focus` after 1 second whenever comp_index changes?

Comment: neither are correct. `useEffect(() => {/*component created, set timer*/const timer=setTimeout(cb, delay);return () => {/*component destroyed, clear timer*/clearTimeout(timer)}})`

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `useEffect` snippets are incorrect.

The value returned by the callback passed to `useEffect` should be a function used for cleaning up things (like clearing the timeout in your case).

So the correct usage looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const timeout = setTimeout(
    () => set_current_focus(index_map[comp_index]),
    1000
  );

  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
}, [comp_index]);
```