# How to ensure latest state in async code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In the below code example, if you click the "Deposit money" button and then click "Lock account" quickly before the API call returns, the money still gets deposited even though the account is locked.

```
export default function App() {
  const [balance, setBalance] = React.useState(1000);
  const [accountLocked, setAccountLocked] = React.useState(false);

  const onDepositMoney = () => {
    fetchAPI().then(() => {
      if (!accountLocked) {
        setBalance((b) => b + 100);
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Current balance: {balance}</div>
      <div>{accountLocked ? "Account locked" : "Account unlocked"}</div>
      <button onClick={onDepositMoney}>Deposit money</button>
      <button onClick={() => setAccountLocked(true)}>Lock account</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-stale-state-in-async-function-jdyqq6)

This is because the `.then` callback is defined using a stale value of `accountLocked: false`, and it cannot read the latest (correct) value of `accountLocked: true`.

What is the canonical way to ensure we have the latest state in React in async code?

- We could combine the two state variables into one, which would fix this issue, but it doesn't seem like a very robust solution.
- We could also consider making a ref to track the latest value of `accountLocked`, but that also seems duplicative and confusing to have a ref and a state referring to the same value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot retrieve current state inside async function in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75253140/cannot-retrieve-current-state-inside-async-function-in-react-js)

Comment: @HenryWoody i suppose it does - i was hoping there was something cleaner than maintaining an extra ref every time you want to read state in an async callback though. it seems like something you'd want to do pretty often.

Comment: that is what I generally do, it's not so bad if you wrap that logic in a custom hook (I have `useUpdatingRef`) so it's just one extra line and you use the ref value instead of the state value.

Comment: Just disable the account lock button while there's an in progress request, and then you don't have to complicate the code.

Comment: @HenryWoody I wish it was not so easy to read stale state generally. However, I agree with you that this ref method seems to be the best we have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've linked this related question: [Cannot retrieve current state inside async function in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75253140/8068625), but I think the question here is a simpler and more general example so I'll provide an answer here.

The value of `accountLocked` is set and locked in when `onDepositMoney` is defined (basically the way [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36314/8068625) works). If you want access to the current value of `accountLocked` you'll need to use a mutable object whose contents can change, which is what refs are for in React.

Here is how you can set up a ref to update with the state value of `accountLocked`:

```
const [accountLocked, setAccountLocked] = React.useState(false);
const accountLockedRef = React.useRef(accountLocked);
accountLockedRef.current = accountLocked;
```

Even though it's only two additional lines, you can write a custom hook to make this pattern easier to use and more contained, like this:

```
function useUpdatingRef(value) {
    const ref = React.useRef(value);
    ref.current = value;
    return ref;
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
function App() {
    const [balance, setBalance] = React.useState(1000);
    const [accountLocked, setAccountLocked] = React.useState(false);
    const accountLockedRef = useUpdatingRef(accountLocked);

    const onDepositMoney = () => {
        fetchAPI().then(() => {
            if (!accountLocked.current) {
                setBalance((b) => b + 100);
            }
        });
    };

    // ...
}
```

This approach will work with other asynchronous code as well like `useEffect` and `setTimeout`.

One thing to note with the custom hook approach is that eslint will require you to include the ref (`accountLockedRef`) in the dependency array for other hooks (e.g. `useEffect`, `useCallback`). This has no effect because the value of the ref is stable but eslint can't tell this.

Comment: You don't actually need to use an effect for this. Just always assign `accountLockedRef.current = accountLocked` during rendering.

Comment: @Bergi true, that's probably more performant and has the benefit of the value updating sooner, I'll update.