# Using useState in a Promise

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a state and asynchronously increment a counter every second whenever the value of the state hasn't changed. When the value changes, it should reset the counter back to 0, and the continue to increment it every second.

The following is what I have, and it's not giving me the desired outcome:

```
interface SomeState {
  key: string;
  count: number;
  state: SomeStates;
}

enum SomeStates {
  IDLE,
  RUNNING,
  WAITING,
}

const MyComponent = (): React.JSX.Element => {
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState<SomeState>({ key: '', count: 0, state: SomeStates.IDLE });
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState<string>('');

  const doJob = (initState: SomeState) => {
    new Promise<SomeState>((res) => res(initState)).then((state) => {
      // this 'if' statement always return true, even when I triggered a new job
      if (myState.key === state.key) {
        setMyState({
          ...myState,
          state: SomeStates.WAITING,
          count: myState.count + 1,
        });
      }
    });
  };

  const sleepJob = (initState: SomeState) => {
    new Promise<SomeState>((res) => setTimeout(() => res(initState), 1000)).then((state) => {
      // this 'if' statement always return true, even when I triggered a new job
      if (myState.key === state.key) triggerJob(myState.key, myState.count);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (myState.state) {
      case SomeStates.RUNNING:
        doJob(_.clone(myState));
        break;
      case SomeStates.WAITING:
        sleepJob(_.clone(myState));
        break;
      default:
    }
  }, [myState.state]);

  const triggerJob = (k: string, count: number = 0): Promise<void> => {
    return Promise.resolve(
      setMyState({
        key: k,
        count: count,
        state: SomeStates.RUNNING,
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <span>
        My value: {myState.key} ({myState.count})
      </span>
      <br />
      <input type="text" value={textValue} onChange={(e) => setTextValue(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => triggerJob(textValue)}>trigger</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Problem with the above code is, if I trigger another job, the previous job is still running. I need to terminate the previous run, but it doesn't seem to be terminating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ensure latest state in async code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566493/how-to-ensure-latest-state-in-async-code)