# window.innerwidth in useEffect dependency array is not calling the callback function

Tags: reactjs, date, react-hooks, rerender

This component is supposed to display the day, date and month in the h2 element on the initial render. The useEffect inside of the function is intended to **change the date to short form when** the window.innerWidth is < 735px and back to long form when not. It is also **intended to re-render the component when the date changes.** The useEffect callback function gets called on first render and displays the date fully as expected depending on the date and innerWidth but not again when the date or the innerWidth change despite the fact that that the day, date, month and innerWidth are all included in the dependency array the **date is checked every 2 seconds** with the setInterval function.

My Code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

let formattedDate
let currentDate = new Date

export default function LocalDate() {

  const [date, setDate] = useState("")
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      currentDate = new Date
    }, 2000)
    console.log("called")
    if (window.innerWidth < 735) {
      formattedDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "short", day: "numeric", month: "short" })
    } else {
      formattedDate = currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", month: "long" })
    }

    let parts = formattedDate.split(" ")
    let formattedDateSwapped = `${parts[0]} ${parts[2]} ${parts[1]}`
    setDate(formattedDateSwapped)

    return clearInterval(interval)
  }, [currentDate.getDay(), currentDate.getDate(), currentDate.getMonth(), window.innerWidth])

  return (
    <h2 id="date">{date}</h2>
  )
}
```

I have looked over it countless times and googled similar issues and looked on many forums and can't find an answer. If anyone has any **suggestions or solutions** for my problem it would be **very much appreciated.** Please keep in mind I have only started learning react about a week ago. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is because the change in window width (specifically `window`) isn't create a change in the `useEffect` dependency array. When it comes to listening to the window, I found that simply [adding and removing event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) (e.g. `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener`) is good way to go...

You're not relying on state to listen to and change a defined value of the page width.
It's also good practice (when working with timeouts and intervals) to be able to control them (i.e. clear them) when the component changes or unmounts (that way you don't get memory leaks).
I make a habit of defining them like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53090848/15291770) (and below) as it's quite declarative and clear as to what you're doing with a timeout. Using `ref`s also doesn't cause a re-render when changing the `timeout.current` value.
The [React Docs](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs#when-to-use-refs) also mention this in "When to use refs".

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React

const shortDate = { weekday: "short", day: "numeric", month: "short" }
const longDate = { weekday: "long", day: "numeric", month: "long" }


const formatDate = () => {
  const currentDate = new Date();
  return window.innerWidth < 735
    ? currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", shortDate)
    : currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US", longDate);
}

function LocalDate () {

  const [formattedDate, setFormattedDate] = useState(formatDate());
  const intervalRef = useRef(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const getNewDate = () => {
        setFormattedDate(formatDate());
        console.log("called");
      }
    
    const getNewDateInterval = () => {
      if (intervalRef.current) {
        console.log("cleared 1")
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
      }
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(getNewDate, 2000)
    }
    
    // call once to start off
    getNewDateInterval()
    // add listener
    window.addEventListener("resize", getNewDate);

    // clean up
    return () => {
      if (intervalRef.current) {
        console.log("cleared 2")
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current)
      }
      window.removeEventListener("resize", getNewDate);
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <h2 id="date">{formattedDate}</h2>
  )
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <LocalDate />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use state objects to allow useEffect to detect changes.
For example, if you create this state:

```
const [currentWidth, setCurrentWidth] = useState(0);
```

Then you can use an interval to fill this state every x seconds:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  setCurrentWidth(window.innerWidth);
}, 2000)
```

Now you can use it in the useEffect control:

```
useEffect(() => { /*do stuff*/ }, [currentWidth])
```

I hope this can help you.