# setInterval is not detecting the useState change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

I want to make an algorithm that every time you log into the page to start a 5 minute counter and while this 5 minute counter is going in I want to make some actions every minute for example.

I tried starting a setTimeout with useEffect and also setting a flag value to know when the 5 minutes are over:

```
const [initialTime, setInitialTime] = useState(true)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('starting counter');
    setTimeout(() => {
      setInitialTime(false)
      console.log('changing the time' + " - " + initialTime);
    }, 5000);
    
  }, [])
```

and under it I added the setInterval function which I want to go off only whenever the flag above (initialTime is true) otherwise not.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (initialTime) {
        //some action
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [])
```

In my head that should work, but setInterval reacts really strange, it doesn't detect the state changes, this is an example log if I place the setTimeout to 5 seconds and setInterval to 1 second:

```
true
true
true
true
changing the time - true
true
```

and then it continues, the setTimeout doesn't even change the state in this case, but even if it does, setInterval doesn't detect it and it still goes through.
I need help completing the algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react hooks and setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981593/react-hooks-and-setinterval)

Comment: If you want to understand what's going on in-depth, here's a good article with a well written hook to get you out of trouble: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` inside a `useEffect is a known issue with React Hooks. Dan Abramov wrote a useful blog post explaining how to resolve it.
https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

The key is to replace

```
useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      if (initialTime) {
        //some action
      }
    }, 1000);
  }, [])
```

with this:

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

Comment: Can you also help me with setTimeout not changing the state when the time passes

Comment: Try adding `initialTime` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` where you call `setTimeout`