# Does setState function of useState hook trigger re-render of whole component or just the returned JSX part of the code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am a beginner in React and I am learning it from a udemy course. Initially I thought the whole code inside the functional component gets re rendered/re run after state update. But then I saw this implementation of countdown before redirect and got confused.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const LoadingToRedirect = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(5);
  let history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((currentCount) => --currentCount);
    }, 1000);

    // redirect once count is equal to 0

    count === 0 && history.push("/");

    // cleanup

    return () => clearInterval(interval);

  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div className="container p-5 text-center">
      <p>Redirecting you in {count} seconds</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoadingToRedirect;
```

So why is setInterval needed here if setCount triggers a re-render of the whole code? Can't we do the same thing with setTimeout? So I tried that and it worked. Surely there is a reason he did it that way? Am I missing something?

Comment: `Can't we do the same thing with setTimeout?` Yes you can, and given that `count` is used as a dependency for the effect, the interval is quite pointless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react hooks and setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981593/react-hooks-and-setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

**Of course React re-renders the whole component but it also depends on some conditions. For example if you look at your code  you have passed count variable as a dependency to useEffect hook, it means if the value of count changes React will render the effect inside of the useEffect hook.**

> Yes, you can achieve the same using setTimeout;setInterval is
> pointless because it totally depends on count variable you passed as a
> dependency.
>
> if you remove count as a dependency then you can easily see it will
> not redirect you the required page.