# Can't read latest state variable in setInterval (Hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I suppose this is because how JS works, but you wouldn't have this problem with classes I suppose. In this code:

```
  let [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  let [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(true);

    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(counter);
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

If I call handleClick **once** (e.g. click button), the value logged on console is always 0 (despite state being updated each time).

This is probably because of the closure. But what if I wanted to see the most recent value of `counter` in such setup?
With classes you could have done `this.state.counter` and it would read latest value.
Is there some workaround with hooks?
[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-r39ws).

---

*Note*: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval) question which asks basically the same. Somehow I didn't encounter it on initial search.

Comment: `const [counter` ... counter is `const` and `setCounter(counter + 1)` doesn't try to change it anyway

Comment: @JaromandaX situation will be same if I write `let`.

Comment: yes ... as I mentioned, `setCounter(counter + 1)` does not change the local variable `counter`

Comment: sure, because counter will remain the same, if you want to observe how it changes you can use `useEffect(() => console.log(counter), [counter])`

Comment: @Kejt Yeah that ok, but it seems there is no way to access the latest value inside setInterval callback in such setup.

Comment: you would maybe need to create your own hook with some reference to current value, but it smells nasty :D

Answer (score 3):

Check the next example, refer to [`setState` in react docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

```
export default function SimpleSnackbar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  let [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  let [, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // Save reference for clearing the interval
  // in your case you firing an interval on every click
  const lastInterval = useRef();

  // Side effect on `open` change.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (lastInterval.current) clearInterval(lastInterval.current);
    if (open) {
      lastInterval.current = setInterval(() => {

        // Functional setState
        setCounter(prevCounterValue => {
          console.log(prevCounterValue);
          return prevCounterValue + 1;
        });

      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [open]);

  function handleClick() {
    setOpen(true);
  }

  function handleClose(event, reason) {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    setOpen(false);
  }

  ...
}
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: ah I know functional `setState`, didn't know hooks had it too. But why not such simple answer:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-of22b? This would satisfy my question already.

Comment: As I mentioned, on every click you will set an interval, when do you clear it? Also, you can clear it within `handleClose`, your choice.

Comment: Ah ok, but that was an existing material demo, I jumped on, in reality I am not interested in that dialog opening, etc. Just the question about `setInterval`..