# React useState Not Storing New Values After UseEffect Intervals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I want to store `"jokes"` and console log a new value every time the interval runs (a get call is made) after 5 seconds. However, the value doesn't render anything after each interval. I'm unsure if jokes are being called and captured since it prints out as `JOKE: []`. My end goal is to create a logic using the `"joke"` state.

If you wish to test it yourself, https://codesandbox.io/s/asynchronous-test-mp2fq?file=/AutoComplete.js

```
  const [joke, setJoke] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random").then((res) => {
        setJoke(res.data.value);
        console.log("JOKE: ", joke); // <- Doesn't print every time it is called.
      });

      console.log("Every 5 seconds");
    }, 5000);

    if (joke.length !== 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log("Returns True");
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't read latest state variable in setInterval (Hooks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904458/cant-read-latest-state-variable-in-setinterval-hooks)

Comment: The reason is Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setJoke` call is actually working. The problem is the `console.log` being called right after `setJoke`. As mentioned in the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state) question, `setState` is async. You can find this issue explained in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value):

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state (see below for details).

You can see that `joke` variable is changing every 5 seconds by adding it to the JSX:

```js
return (
    <>
    {JSON.stringify(joke)}
      <Autocomplete
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        open={open}
        onOpen={() => {
          setOpen(true);
        }}
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal you have to, for example, split your code into two `useEffect` calls:

```
  const [joke, setJoke] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      axios.get("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random").then((res) => {
        if (res.data.value.length !== 0) {
          setJoke(res.data.value);
          clearInterval(interval);
          console.log("Returns True");
        }
      });

      console.log("Every 5 seconds");
    }, 5000);


    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // here you can write any side effect that depends on joke
  }, [joke]);
```