# How to handle state using Redux with periodical updates and React Hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

### My Use Case

I am just starting with React (Native) with Hooks and Redux and have some issues understanding some parts of the state update concept for my use case. I am currently working on a React Native App that should update data every full minute. So if the user enters the app at say `11h:31m:27s`,

1. the initial state should be shown, then
2. a `setTimeout` handles the first update with the offset to reach the full minute (in this case `33s` to reach `11h:32m:00s`)
3. a `setInterval` handles the minutely update of the data from now on.

### My Issue

Currently, with the below code the `console.log("Reducer Fires!")` inside the `reducers.js` file is fired increasingly more with every new minute (e.g. only once in the first minute, then two times in the second minute and so on). So I feel that I am still doing something wrong with how I handle the state of my data together with the `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` logic. Could somebody review my code below and point me to the errors I am doing?

### My Code (so far)

some dummy **`data`**:

```
export const DATA = [
    {"id": 1, "myAttr": 0},
    {"id": 2, "myAttr": 4},
    {"id": 3, "myAttr": 8},
    {"id": 4, "myAttr": 12},
]
```

---

the **`App.js`** file with the redux store:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { View } from 'react-native';

// Components
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent";
import dataReducer from "./store/reducers";

//Create Redux store
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mydata: dataReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

export default function App() {

  return (
    <Provider store={store} >
      <View>
        <MyComponent />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

---

the **`actions.js`** file storing my Redux action:

```
//Action to update the data
export const UPDATE_DATA = "UPDATE_DATA";

export const updateData = () => {
    return { type: UPDATE_DATA }
}
```

---

the **`reducers.js`** file to store the reducers:

```
import { DATA } from "../data/data";
import { UPDATE_DATA } from "./actions";

// Initial state when app launches
const initState = {
    data: DATA
}

const dataReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_DATA:
            //Update an attribute in each object of the data array

            const updatedData = state.data.map((i) => {
                const newMyAttr = i.myAttr + 1;
                return { ...i, myAttr: newMyAttr }
            }
            )

            console.log("Reducer Fires!");
            return { ...state, data: updatedData }

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default dataReducer;
```

---

the **`component`** where I am trying to update the state:

```
import React, { useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const myData = useSelector(state => state.mydata.data);

    let start = new Date();
    const fullMinuteOffset = (60 - start.getSeconds()) * 1000;

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const saveData = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch(updateData())
    }, [dispatch]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            saveData()
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                saveData()
            }, 60000)

            return () => clearInterval(interval);
        }, fullMinuteOffset);

        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
    }, [saveData, fullMinuteOffset]);

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>{myData[0].myAttr}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the component renders it will have a new value of fullOffserMinute and it's a dependency of useEffect thus registering a new interval call.

Here's a simplified working example of your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-panini-k35s1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```js
  // the relevant part of it
  let start = new Date();
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const fullMinuteOffset = (60 - start.getSeconds()) * 1000;

  function timerAction() {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("-- use effect --");
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("save data timeout");
      timerAction();
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log("save data interval");
        timerAction();
      }, 5000);

      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, fullMinuteOffset);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
```

You should also read the answers here if you're going to update local state in intervals: 
[State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval)

Comment: Thanks for this. When I use the code the way you wrote it, my issue with the multiple prints is gone.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you change the useEffect dependencies to just this: `[saveTime, fullMinuteOffset]` -> to this `[]`. It seems like everytime that component updates that useEffect call might be registering more intervals