# how to use setInterval without useEffect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

if i used setInterval(line 15) without useEffect than it gives result 2^n-1(0,1,3,7,15,31,63...) instead of(0,1,2,3,4,..)  . so i have some question
1)why i am getting that output when I directly  called setInterval without useeffect                    2)is there any way if I change setCount(line 9) and its gives correct output by use setInterval directly without useEffect(as I did)
3)  if the use of setInterval is not possible without useEffcet than why it is not possible?

if i put setInterval in useEffect and render initially once( line 12,13,14) than it gives correct output.....
but I do not get the correct output when I use directly setInterval. what is diff bet them?
in both cases, I call setInterval once but the output is diff.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    
    export default function IncorrectDependency() {
    
    const [count,setCount]=useState(0)
    
    const inc=()=>{
        // console.log(count)
        setCount(preVal=>preVal+1)
    //    setCount(count+1)
    }
    // useEffect(()=>{
    //     setInterval(inc,1000)},[]
    // )
    setInterval(inc,1000)
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{count}</h1>
               
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to use it without useEffect? In anycase I recommend using [useInterval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-interval)

Comment: i want to understand concept of this. i did't get what is diif  bet both of them

Comment: Good reasoning. Aloks answer has got everything you need.

Comment: But see  also: http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2020/04/09/react-hooks-and-setinterval/

Comment: thank you for kind response . i add comment in that answer pls read that.till i read this blog which you send. thank you again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval)

Comment: my state is updating 2^n-1 instaed of n+1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222759/discussion-between-meet-vaghsiya-and-dwjohnston).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When we do a set state, functional components will re-execute from top to bottom, how ever when we use useState, useCallbacks etc.. they will not re-initialize as variables, functions,

So in this case, `setInterval` will re-initialize on each and every `setCount`, because of the state got changed,

step by step

- in the 1st second there will be one setInterval, and call setCount and component is ready to rerender
- when re-redering, start executing functional component from top-to-bottom it sees `setInterval` again and it will trigger it, so now we have two `setIntervals`
- so on it will add multiple setIntervals on each second, because we don't clear it, so you should see the number printed in the browser will not take a second, but less than a second when time goes by.

You can achieve the expected result without `useEffect` by clearing the previous interval on each re-render which is happen due to `setCount`

create a variable to hold the set interval, [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dlecau)

```
const interval = null;
//this should be declare out side the component,
//because if we declare it inside the component it will redeclare,
//and the reference to the previous setInterval will be lost in that case no-way to clear the setInterval.
export default function IncorrectDependency() {
    ....
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    interval = setInterval(inc, 1000);
    ....
 }
```

alternatively react has a hook which can hold the same variables without re-initializing on each renderings, check it out [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

here is a [code-demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ictqd6)

```
const intvl = useRef(null);
....

if (intvl?.current) {
    clearInterval(intvl.current);
}

intvl.current = setInterval(inc, 1000);
.....
```

Comment: Note that the correct way to do this is still `useEffect`. I'm clarifying for the next reader who might assume that this is the correct way to do intervals (it's not).

Answer (score 1):

when you directly use setInterval what is happening as this is a function it will be called on state change so again a setInterval will be triggered and so on which actually give you the incorrect result, so you shouldn't use setInterval without use effect, also on unmount you should clearthe interval

Comment: thank you your response. but i still did't get how setInterval will trigger again.  i mean setInterval called function every second as per above example than how it trigger setInterval again? and you mean state change but react-dom change value only count than how and why it trigger setInterval?

Comment: it is a function , react will call the function and when the function is called the line with setInterval will be trigered, you can put any console before setInterval and see on every state change the  console will we called, in class component render function was called  but in functional component whole function will run  except hooks

Answer (score -2):

Dan Abramov explains why this isn't a good idea:

"it’s not the idiomatic way to do it. eg it won’t work correctly if you have multiple instances of the same component. it breaks the rules — it does a side effect (setInterval) during rendering, which the page said you should not do :) once you break the rules, all bets are off"

https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1577395235340095501?s=20&t=nNnYyjLvHs5by_dqF5l8zg