# React: setInterval Not working after one interval

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, setinterval

**My Goal:**

I'm trying to build a component that when you give it `props.items` and `props.fadeEvery`, it will act as a text rotator. I eventually want it to fade in an out, but I'm having trouble with my `window.setInterval`.

**Possible Issue:**

I'm calling `setIndex` in the `useEffect` hook, but is that not good practice? How an I have it iterate through the array items infinitely?

**TextFade.tsx**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// TypeScript Type: Props
interface Props {
  items: Array<string>,
  fadeEvery: number,
};

// Component: Text Fade
const TextFade: React.FC<Props> = (props): JSX.Element => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState<number>(0);

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID: number = window.setInterval(() => {
      // End Of Array
      if (index > props.items.length) {
        // Set Data
        setIndex(0);
      }
      else {
        // Set Data
        setIndex(index + 1);
      }
    }, props.fadeEvery * 1000);

    // Clear Timeout On Component Unmount
    return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="text-fade-container">
      <p id="text-fade-text">{props.items[index]}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

// Exports
export default TextFade;
```

Comment: `index` is in what's called a closure.  Your use effect has been told to only render once `[]`.. So you need to use the callback version of `setIndex`

Comment: Just another heads up, if your using `setInterval`, it's most likely better to `clearInterval` not `clearTimeout`.  MDN does say the ID's are shared, but for clarity its best to keep them in sync.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your index values are taken from initital closure and it won't update unless useEffect callback is called again. You can instead use functional way to update state

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID: number = window.setInterval(() => {
      // End Of Array 
      setIndex(prevIdx => {
         if (prevIdx > props.items.length) {
            // Set Data
             return 0;
         }
         else {
           // Set Data
           return prevIdx + 1;
          }
      })
      
    }, props.fadeEvery * 1000);

    // Clear Timeout On Component Unmount
    return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Perfect that worked! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Below I've knocked up a snippet using the callback version of setState, this avoid the closure issue you get by using useEffect with `[]`..

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;


const TextFade = (props) => {
  // React Hooks: State
  const [ index, setIndex ] = useState(0);

  // React Hooks: Lifecycle Methods
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID: number = window.setInterval(() => {
      // End Of Array
      setIndex(index => 
        index + 1 >= props.items.length
          ? 0
          : index + 1);
    }, props.fadeEvery * 1000);

    // Clear Timeout On Component Unmount
    return () => window.clearInterval(timeoutID);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="text-fade-container">
      <p id="text-fade-text">{props.items[index]}</p>
    </div>
  );
};



ReactDOM.render(<TextFade items={['one','two', 'three']} fadeEvery={1}/>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="mount"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Keith said:

> index is in what's called a closure. Your use effect has been told to
> only render once [].. So you need to use the callback version of
> setIndex

So, your `useEffect` hook will be:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutID: number = window.setInterval(() => {
      // End Of Array
      if (index > props.items.length) {
        // Set Data
        setIndex(0);
      } else {
        // Set Data
        setIndex(index + 1);
      }
    }, props.fadeEvery * 1000);

    // Clear Timeout On Component Unmount
    return () => window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, [index]);
```

Here is the working demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-ishizaka-lurtg?file=/src/TextFade.tsx).

Comment: Don't rely on comments sticking around. They are often removed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, @HereticMonkey.

Comment: This is using the dependency of `useEffect` rather than the setState callback, and is certainly another option.  You could even then change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.  If the useEffect could be time consuming, I would even say this is the better option.