# Why is the setstate not updating the value in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am using reactjs in my application . The currid_s is set to value -1 initially.. later after button click it is set to 2 but the timer doesnot show the updated value in the Console. Why?
Here is the code

```
 
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [currid_s, setcurrid_s] = React.useState(-1);
  const handless = () => {
    console.log("yess");
    setcurrid_s(2);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(currid_s, "yes");
    getPosts();

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getPosts();
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  // const all_pooo=()=>{
  //   console.log(curr,"dddd")
  // }
  const getPosts = async () => {
    console.log(currid_s);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handless}>gggg</button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the link to code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/embed/beautiful-ardinghelli-dg1r4?file=/src/App.js&codemirror=1

Comment: Callback function of the interval has a closure over the value of `currid_s` that was in-effect when the timer interval set. You need to set a new interval whenever `currid_s` is updated. You can do this by adding `currid_s` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: @Yousaf but how is the interval affecting currid_s value?

Comment: Can u change in the codesandbox @Yousaf please?

Comment: It looks to me like you are complicating things in your code. Why have `setInterval` run with `onClick` when you can just use `useEffect`  to call `getPost` based on changes made to `currid_s`

Comment: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-hoover-lnduq?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @UdenduAbasili  the useEffect is used as componentdidmount so that the getposts() function runs every two seconds to get backend stuff... Now when I click on the button the state changes for currid_s but it's not updating on the getposts function? If you have any alternatives to this please tell me those

Comment: @TusharShahi what do you mean? `setInterval` is not changing its value; it just calls a function, i.e. `getPosts`, that logs the value of `currid_s`.

Comment: @Rocky I know what `useEffect` is. I am say that instead of using `setInterval` to call your backend, why not call the backend only when `currid_s` changes.

Comment: @Yousaf I just checked your code ... I have many react hooks should I include all of them in it?

Comment: Please look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval

Comment: I get data from backend... After clicking on the data which came from backend on ui the state changes and should console in getposts @Udendu Abasili

Comment: @Yousaf sorry. I missed that. Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get your new state value inside your `setInterval` because you're storing an old version of `getPosts` inside your interval callback function.

What happens is when `currid_s` updates, your App component rerenders, and a new `getPosts` function is initialized containing the new value. However, `setInterval` callback function stores a reference to an old `getPosts` function containing the old value. This old `getPosts` function would print the copy of the old `currid_s` value that was assigned upon mounting of the App component. Javascript does not support referencing of primitives, that's why your old `getPosts` function does not have the new value.

If you want to print your `currid_s` whenever it updates, just do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(currid_s)
}, [currid_s])
```

Comment: I have many react hooks in my website. Should I add all these in the dependency?

Answer (score 2):

You can change `currid_s` from a `useState()` to a [`useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) so that its value is accessible from the closure that the `setInterval` callback captures:

```js
const { useRef, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const currid_s = useRef(-1);
  const handless = () => {
    currid_s.current = 2;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getPosts = () => {
      console.log(currid_s.current);
    };

    getPosts();

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      getPosts();
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handless}>Click me</button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```