# updated state value are not updated inside function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

react state updated values are shown in use Effect but inside function only shown an old value.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
```

I am trying to update the counter value inside a set interval function

```
 const handleIncrease = () => {
clearInterval(intervalval);
if (counter < 10) {
  let increment = setInterval(() => {
    console.log("isCounterContinue@handleIncrease", counter);
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, 1000);
  setIntervalval(increment);
}
```

};
inside useEffect updated values are shown. but inside function handleIncrease only show the old value
Basically, I am trying to do counter value is not increase when it's more than 30.

code Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-cdn-zzbs2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [State not updating when using React state hook within setInterval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval)

Comment: The code in your codesandbox *seems* to function as you describe wanting... but it also doesn't match the snippet you've shared here. What is the issue?

Comment: inside handleIncrease function counter value is not updated. so if I try to add condition(based on counter state) is not applied inside handleIncrease function

Comment: `handleIncrease` is only called when a button is clicked, with the current state. What is there to update in the click handler? I think what you are really after is accessing the updated `counter` state in the interval's callback, which "ticks" once every second.

Comment: in click handler every 1000 ms after update counter state. but it is not shown updated value inside handleIncrease function. i am confused inside useEffect updated value are shown but inside handleIncrease counter value are not shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleIncrease` is only called when a button is clicked, with the current state. There is nothing to update in the click handler. I think what you are really after is accessing the updated `counter` state in the interval's callback, which "ticks" once every second. Or more accurately, respond to the `isCounterContinue` state toggling false to stop the interval when a limit is hit.

Use a ref to hold a reference to the interval timer and set/clear using this instead of a state that goes stale in enclosures.

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ counter });
    if (counter >= 5) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [counter]);

  const handleIncrease = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleDecrease = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>{counter}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleDecrease}>Decrease</button>
        <button onClick={handleStop}>Stop</button>
        <button onClick={handleIncrease}>Increase</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Suggestion

The increment/decrement handlers are basically identical other than what they add to the count. Use a curried function to handle both cases by closing over an incrementing value. Since the "stop" handler shares logic to clear the interval, use the fact that `0` is a falsey value and only restart an interval timer for truthy (i.e. non-zero) number values and use one single handler for all three buttons.

```
const handleIncrease = (val) => () => {
  clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  if (val) {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter((prev) => prev + val);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

...

<button onClick={handleIncrease(-1)}>Decrease</button>
<button onClick={handleIncrease(0)}>Stop</button>
<button onClick={handleIncrease(1)}>Increase</button>
```

[image: Edit updated-state-value-are-not-updated-inside-function-in-react]

Comment: it's working, can you please explain the reason behind why without Ref, updated value is not shown inside handleIncrease function.

Comment: @ShatishDesai It is only displaying the current `counter` value when clicked, not when the interval "ticks". If you continued to click the "Increase" button each second you'll see the updated `counter` state. If you wait a few seconds and *then* click "Increase" again, you'll see the current `counter` state.