# How to stop setInterval inside useEffect hook when certain value is reached? [React]

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state variable

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

and `useEffect` hook

```
let intervalID;
useEffect(() => {
  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    setValue(value => value+1);
  }, 100)
}, [])
```

I want the `setInterval` function to stop when `value` reaches `100`; How can I achieve this?

I tried `if(value < 100 ) clearInterval(intervalID)` inside `setInterval` but it didn't work.

Comment: If you want the interval to be invoked only once, why'd you not want to use `setTimeout`?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni I don't want the interval to be invoked once, but multiple times, until value reaches 100.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `intervalID` is resetting on every state update. you need to store intervalId in ref so that it doesn't changes between state updates.

```js
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  // store timeoutID in ref, initialy it's null
  const timeoutID = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    // store timeoutID in ref current property
    timeoutID.current = setTimeout(() => {
      if (value > 100) {
        // clear interval
        clearTimeout(timeoutID.current);
        timeoutID.current = null;
        return;
      }
      setValue((value) => value + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // clear interval if component unmounts before value reaches 100
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID.current);
  }, [value]);
  return value;
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. `setInterval` keeps running

Comment: updated the answer. you might want to check this https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024497/6514790

Comment: This fixed my mistake of storing the interval ID in state instead of ref.

Answer (score 1):

This problem requires keen observation and know-how of the working of `useEffect`.
Okay let's break this down, let's consider your code and see why it doesn't work:

```
let intervalID;
useEffect(() => {
  intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    setValue(value => value+1);
  }, 100)
}, [])
```

We can notice that the dependency array is empty, meaning `useEffect` runs only once when it is mounted. So right after the component is mounted, your `useEffect` runs and the `setInterval` is triggered to increment the `value` every 100ms. Since there are no conditions given when to stop, this keeps going on forever. Further, you are not making use of the `current` property on the `intervalId` instance (Although it is not mandatory, it's a good practice).

In order to get this working, we'd want to add some conditions to stop the interval after the `value` reaches 100. This condition can be checked when `useEffect` is invoked every time after the value is incremented. To invoke `useEffect` when value is incremented, we can add `value` as a dependency array. Now that we're invoking the function, the next part is fairly simple and that is, checking if the value has reached 100 or not, this could be done using a simple `if` condition.
Since we've added a dependency array to `useEffect` and it runs whenever `value` changes, it is important to clean up the previously created intervals, using `clearInterval`. `clearInterval` should be invoked before creating a new interval, and the best time to clear the interval is when it is unmounting.
So all-in-all you could do something like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  let intervalID = useRef(null); //using useRef hook to maintain state changes across rerenders.
  useEffect(() => {
    
    if (value < 100) {
      intervalID.current = setInterval(() => { //Proceed to set interval if value is less than 100
        setValue((value) => value + 1);

      }, 100);
    } 
    

    return () => clearInterval(intervalID.current); //clear previous interval when unmounting.
  }, [value]);
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello{value}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Since an interval is created and destroyed during each mounting/unmounting phase, you could alternatively use `setTimeout` also, which again would give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

const intervalID = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    intervalID.current = setInterval(() => {
        if (value < 3) {
            console.log('Set Interval')
            setValue(value => value + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Clear Interval')
            clearInterval(intervalID.current);
            intervalID.current = null;
        }
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID.current)

}, [value])

return (
    <>Interval Value: {value}</>
)
```

Comment: I have called setInterval till value = 3. So you can set as per your logic.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `setInterval` keeps running