# React won't reload function despite state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state that tracks the window width:

```
const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth)
```

In `useEffect`, I create a resize `eventListener` which sets the `state` to the new width:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('resize', () => {
      setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth)
    })
  }, [])
```

Lastly, I have a `function` test that logs the `innerWidth` every 5 seconds, with an `interval` started in `useEffect`

```
  function test() {
    console.log(innerWidth)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     setInterval(test, 5000)
  }, [])
```

Unfortunately, despite any resize that happen, the `test()` `function` keeps on logging the original `innerWidth` value.

How can I tell react to reload the `test` `function` as well?

EDIT:

The perpetual log of the innerWidth was just a simplification of my actual use case. Actually, the timer is shifting an element on the x-axis, and I need to know when it exceeds the width to stop the execution and start again.

Creating and invalidating a loop every time the window changes, like in several answers you've given, temporarily stops the shifting of my element, as the loop gets invalidated. I would like to avoid this.

Comment: @S.Marx That will just create new intervals every time the width changes. Wouldn't it?

Comment: It would, which means that `useEffect` would need to return a function which cancels the interval.  So every change to that state would result in canceling the old interval and starting a new one.  Which kind of makes the interval unnecessary... Why not just log the value directly in the `useEffect` any time it changes instead of re-logging the same value every 5 seconds?

Comment: Here `useRef` can help you to capture latest values.  When the function is defined inside `setInterval` it's taking initial value because of closure(the time when this function is initialised).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was wrapping the innerWidth into an object, so that it is passed by reference and it 'updates' in the `test` `function`.

```
const innerWidthWrapper = {width: window.innerWidth}

  useEffect(() => {
     innerWidthWrapper.width = window.innerWidth
    })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 3):

The `useEffect` created a closure around the original values, so that's all it ever logs.  You'd need the effect to update any time the value changes, by adding it to the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(test, 5000)
}, [innerWidth])
```

This would of course create a *new* interval on every state change.  So the `useEffect` should return a function which cancels the interval:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const x = setInterval(test, 5000);
  return () => clearInterval(x);
}, [innerWidth])
```

That way there's only one interval running at any given time.

Though this begs the question... *Why?*  If the goal is to log the value of `innerWidth` to observe its changes, then why re-log the same value every 5 seconds indefinitely?  Skip the `test` function and the interval entirely and just log the value any time it changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(innerWidth);
}, [innerWidth])
```

Comment: Posted an edit.

Comment: @RiccardoPerego: That sounds like a somewhat different problem.  The question asked was specifically about `useEffect`, it's closure, and how to update the values therein.  Whereas *"temporarily stops the shifting of my element"* sounds like a kind of animation issue that needs to be smoother?  There could be a variety of ways to address that, whether using smaller interval and calculating timing more deliberately or using a different approach altogether.  That would likely warrant a separate question, to include a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the test function to an anonymous function?

```
const test = () => {
    console.log(innerWidth);
};
```

Change you useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth);
    });
}, [setInnerWidth]);
```

Comment: That doesn't change.

Comment: document.addEventListener doesnt trigger when I test it out. Can you change it to window.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Your issue using the interval function is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024497/10352429)

This code works for me by logging the state variable using the effect hook:

```js
const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

useEffect(() => {
  const updateWidth = () => {
    setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth);
  };
  window.addEventListener("resize", updateWidth);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(innerWidth);
}, [innerWidth]);
```

I added the eventlistener using the window object.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-sky-ehqtyl?file=/src/App.js:110-406)