# React: settimeout's callback doesn't have updated state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval

**I want to call a function at regular intervals and update state inside it.**

I started with a useEffect but eventually ended up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024496/state-not-updating-when-using-react-state-hook-within-setinterval). I tried using Ref.current to store the interval and clear it every time in the function and recreate it but it still wasn't working. Something like this

```
const drawBall = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  // Access state and update it
  intervalRef.current = setInterval(drawBall, 1000);
}
```

I dropped the idea and thought of using a simple setTimeout. Everytime `drawBall` is called, it calls a new Timeout, even if the closure takes the value at the time of being called, it still will have the updated value as the value at the time of calling is updated. But it is not working as expected, the function still gets the old value even though the value is being updated correctly. The code goes like this -

```
const drawBall = () => {
 console.log(ballPos); // Shows initial value in every call (not the expected behaviour)
 setBallPos(prevVal => {
   console.log(prevVal); // Shows the right value
   return {
       x: prevVal.x + 2,
       y: prevVal.y + 2
   }
 });

 setTimeout(drawBall, 1000);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Edit:
Switching to use-effect doesn't help. It updates `ballPos` correctly, but that was happening before too. The issue still remains that when I access `ballPos.x` even inside the same useEffect, it shows the original value, not the updated one.

This is the new useEffect code

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {

            const canvas = gameBoard.current;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            let currX = ballPos.x;
            let currY = ballPos.y;
            currX += defaultDX;
            currY += defaultDY;
            console.log(currX, currY); // Shows Old Value
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(currX, currY, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            ctx.fill();

            setBallPos((prevVal) => {
                return {
                    x: prevVal.x + defaultDX,
                    y: prevVal.y + defaultDY
                }
            });
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: In the `setTimeout` variant, outside the state setter, `ballPos` is a closure over the immutable state value at the time the function was defined. It would probably be better to set and clear an interval in a `useEffect` call so the loop will be stopped once the component is unmounted

Comment: You should read this article https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/. And the final solution here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xvyl15375w

Comment: @DustInComp , why does it take the value of the time when the function was defined? Shouldn't it take the value when the function was called?

Comment: @Exter The "value when the function was called" is the **immutable state** of a previous render call. The value of the `ballPos` const you get a closure over never changes (and you shouldn't be using it asynchronously). The `ballPos` argument that's passed to the callback you provide to `setBallPos` will always be the current value at the time the state is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're updating the state correctly, you continue to use the old value to draw on the canvas because the `ballPos` reference inside the interval callback is not aware of state changes.

You could use the new state value for the draw call as shown below, or move the `requestAnimationFrame` part to its own Effect entirely.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setBallPos((prevVal) => {
            const newBallPos = {
                x: prevVal.x + defaultDX,
                y: prevVal.y + defaultDY
            };
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                const canvas = gameBoard.current;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                console.log(newBallPos);
                ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(newBallPos.x, newBallPos.y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.fill();
            });
            return newBallPos;
        });
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
}, [])
```

Comment: Moved the drawBall logic to a new useEffect with `ballPos` as a dependency, it worked, Thank you for clearing the doubts

Comment: @Exter In that case, make sure to use `clearAnimationFrame` similar to `clearInterval` as well.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue and to continuously update the state at regular intervals, you should consider using the `useEffect` hook along with `setInterval` to update the state.

```
const [ballPos, setBallPos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setBallPos((prevPos) => ({
      x: prevPos.x + 2,
      y: prevPos.y + 2,
    }));
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(interval); // clean up the interval on component unmount
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: This still causes the same issue, I updated the question